# Are there any lenses for the Sony HX200V to make better quality photos?

Tags: lens, sony

My sister has just bought the Sony DSC-HX200V camera. She mainly uses the camera to take photos of views and portraits of children (for university work). Are there any lenses available to buy for this to make better quality photos? If so what?

Answer (score 2):

That camera has a fixed 30x optical zoom lens, so there are no alternative lenses to buy for it.

There are third party wide-angle and close-up adaptors available that screw on the front, but that will likely decrease image quality by introducing additional elements in the optical path. I would not recommend buying one of these until you find you really need it.

The built in lens provides a 25mm equivalent field of view at the wide end so that should be sufficient for landscapes.

Comment: Minor correction: 27mm-e at the wide end. Would you still consider that sufficient?

Comment: for years most compacts could only muster a 30mm or 35mm equivalent field of view so yeah I'd be surprised if 27mm caused many people to reach for the wide converter.